# `this.some_property` becomes undefined inside anonymous callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, anonymous-function

So I can't quite figure out why the variable **this.tasks** becomes undefined inside of the add event listener I have inside of my goal object. I have a feeling it might have something to do with asynchronous programming(which I still don't fully understand). Sorry I'm a bit of a JS noob, but if you guys could explain to me what I'm doing wrong and what might be a better solution that would be awesome! Thanks.

```
function Goal(name) {
        this.gDiv =  document.createElement('div');
        this.name = name || "goal";
        this.tasks = document.createElement('ul');
        //Sets the styling and content and adds it to the parent element
        this.initialize = function() {
            this.gDiv.className = "default";
            this.gDiv.setAttribute("id", this.name);
            this.gDiv.innerHTML = this.name;
            elem.appendChild(this.gDiv);

            this.gDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(this.tasks, this.gDiv.nextSibling);
            this.tasks.style.display = "none";


        };  
        //Creates a list underneath the a dive associated with the Goal object
        this.addTask = function(task) {
            var newLi = document.createElement('li');
                newLi.innerHTML = task;
                this.tasks.appendChild(newLi);
        };

        this.gDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
            alert(this.tasks);              
        });

    }
```

Thank you guys! You all answered my question! I'd been scratching my head at this for a while. Kudos to you all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The scope changes when you enter that anonymous closure and 'this' changes. You can hack around it by doing

```
var self = this;
```

And then using self in place of this (eg):

```
function Goal(name) {
    var self = this;

    /* ... */

    this.gDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert(self.tasks);              
    });
```

If you're using jQuery you could do something nicer:

```
this.gDiv.addEventListener('click', $.proxy(function() {
    alert(this.tasks);
 }, this));
```

Either way works just fine.

EDIT: In ES6, arrow functions can be used instead as they don't bind their own "this", so it becomes even simpler:

```
this.gDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(this.tasks);
 });
```

Comment: Your answer was good. You changed it and now I'd like to know what makes you think that using a jQuery method is better?

Comment: In a large codebase, I see the 'var self = this;' idiom all the time and it gets clunky, especially once you have further nesting of closures. This ensures that your 'this' is always what you intend.

Comment: Or could use call method

Answer (score 10):

Here is a comparison of some methods (including your problem), to give you a taster, and to try and explain things a little.

```js
// This is the problem that you have,
// where `this` inside the anonymous function
// is a different scope to it's parent
function Test1(something) {
  // `this` here refers to Test1's scope
  this.something = something;
  setTimeout(function() {
    // `this` here refers to the anonymous function's scope
    // `this.something` is `undefined` here
    console.log(this.something);
  }, 1000);
};

new Test1('Hello');
```

```js
// This solution captures the parent `this` as `test2This`,
// which can then be used inside the anonymous function
function Test2(something) {
  var test2This = this;

  this.something = something;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(test2This.something);
  }, 1000);
}

new Test2('World');
```

```js
// This solution captures `this` as `test3This` in an `IIFE closure`
// which can then be used in the anonymous function
// but is not available outside of the `IIFE closure` scope
function Test3(something) {
  this.something = something;
  (function(test3This) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(test3This.something);
    }, 1000);
  }(this));
}

new Test3('Goodbye');
```

```js
// This method requires that you load an external library: jQuery
// and then use it's `$.proxy` method to achieve the basics of 
// Test3 but instead of being referred to as `test3This` the
// outer scope `this` becomes the inner scope `this`
// Ahh, that's much clearer?
function Test4(something) {
  this.something = something;
  setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    console.log(this.something);
  }, this), 1000);
}

new Test4('Mum');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// This is approximately what jQuery's `$.proxy` does
// but without having to load the whole library
function Test5(something) {
  this.something = something;
  setTimeout((function(func, context) {
    return function() {
      func.call(context);
    };
  }(function() {
    console.log(this.something);
  }, this)), 1000);
}

new Test5('Dad');
```

```js
// Lets create the proxy method as a reuseable
function proxy(func, context) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

  return function() {
    return func.apply(
      context, 
      args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
    );
  };
}

// and now using it
function Test6(something) {
  this.something = something;
  setTimeout(proxy(function() {
    console.log(this.something);
  }, this), 1000);
}

new Test6('Me want cookies');
```

Then we have [Function#bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
function Test7(something) {
  this.something = something;
  setTimeout(function() {
    // `this` was bound to the parent's `this` using bind
    console.log(this.something);
  }.bind(this), 1000);
};

new Test7('Num num');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
```

And most recently [ES2015 Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
function Test8(something) {
  this.something = something;
  setTimeout(() => console.log(this.something), 1000);
};

new Test8('Whoop');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this all together! You're a champ!

Comment: Yeah, this is a great write up. Thanks very much @Xotic750 -- I will strive to be as thorough with answers as you have been in the future. I have to admit I'm relatively new to JavaScript and this is one of the best explanations I've ever seen of proxy functions in JS.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, arrow functions were introduced, which do not bind their own this.

[MDN for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

So creating an anonymous function using the arrow syntax is probably the easiest way to overcome this issue nowadays. It is supported by all major browsers currently, except IE.

Answer (score 0):

the keyword 'this' changes in it's meaning for an event handler against a constructor

please refer to the MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler

Comment: Thanks for the reference Tim!

Comment: I would recommend to use the docs, rather than follow idiomatic quick fixes without deeper understanding.