# Setting variable in outer scope from inside a promise

Tags: javascript, scope, promise

I'm trying to update a value outside of the scope of a promise function but am having difficulty wrapping my head around how to do so. I thought setting self = this would correct scope issues as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769460/javascript-object-variable-becomes-undefined-inside-anonymous-function), but self.value is still 0 outside of the scope of the promise. The relevant code is below.

```
window.App = {
     foo: function() {
          var self = this;
          self.value = 0;

          self.func1 = function() {
               func2().then(function(result1) {
                    return func3(result1);
               }).then(function(result2) {
                    self.value = result2;
               })
          }
     },
     bar: function() {
          var fooObject = new this.foo();
          fooObject.func1();
     },
     baz: function() {
          var fooObject = new this.foo();
          func4(fooObject.value);
     }
}
```

How would I be able to set the value of self.value inside the promise? I would like to access this value later on in the code within App via foo.value.

Comment: Feel free to simply use arrow functions instead of the `self = this` antipattern, arrow functions are great

Comment: Also, the syntax is invalid - you can't call `.then` on a function expression (and you have mismatched parentheses)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can't? doesn't this just assign result to be the value returned by func2() after it has been executed? Also yeah sorry about the mimatched brackets, I didn't copy+paste to try and keep things simple

Comment: I can see that App.foo is function ... how can you access it like  App.foo.value ..??

Comment: `after it has been executed?` Yes, but you'd have to turn the whole thing into a function for that. (or, you'd have to immediately invoke the first function, but then `func1` would be a `Promise`, not a function)

Comment: @PraveenN sorry about that! I would be calling it inside window.App, so I would only need to call foo.value. Unless I can't just assign it an object like that since it's a function? I've been able to do foo.func1() just fine so I thought I could do foo.value as well. I'm new to js so bear with me

Comment: @CertainPerformance you're right, in my attempt to simplify I actually made errors. I fixed it and now it represents exactly what I need to do

Comment: Works just fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/9upkL63a/

Comment: `self.this` will work as expected, and "*self.value is still 0 outside of the scope of the promise*" is not because of a reference problem but rather because promises are asynchronous. Show us where you are calling  `func1` and where/when you are accessing `.value`.

Comment: @Bergi updated to show use of `func1` and `.value` call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @akivjh But where are you *calling* `App.bar` and `App.baz`? Also notice that you have two different `fooObject`s created by two constructor calls, so it *cannot* work to access the result `.value` on one of them after calling `.func1()` on the other.

Comment: @Bergi yeah I think having 2 different objects was the issue, I used the callback function method in the link posted by zero298 to do what I need to

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example of promise that I tried to build like your code:

```js
window.App = {
   foo: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.value = 0;
        this.func2 = function(){
          return 1;
       }

        self.func1 = function(){
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               console.log("before execute value: " + self.value);
               resolve(self.func2());
          }).then(function(result) {
               self.value = result;
               console.log("promise then value: " + self.value);
          });
        }
   }   
}
var o = new window.App.foo();
var promise = o.func1();
console.log("outside value: "+o.value);
promise.then(function(){
  console.log("outside promise then value: "+o.value);
})
```